# Do puffshrooms work on Phantom Ganons?

Tags: zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom

In Tears of the Kingdom, Gloom Spawn (the gloom hands that are found in various places) can easily be killed by bomb arrows from bullet time. However, after you defeat them, they turn into a miniboss, Phantom Ganon. However, puffshrooms are capable of neutralizing even Boss Bokoblins and Lynels, although you can't sneakstrike the latter. So I'm curious, do puffshrooms work on Phantom Ganons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they do not. I just ran across one, and tried a variety of items against him (puffshroom, ice fruit, shock fruit, various chuchu jellies). It appears Phantom Ganons are immune to all. Specifically for the puffshroom, Phantom Ganon did not stop moving towards Link. Even if I moved and he was centered in the puffshroom smoke, he would adjust and keep moving straight towards me. He also did not get the expected '?' in the puffshroom to signify that he lost sight of Link.

Comment: Do you know if the elemental bonus damage still affects them?

Comment: @User23415 I'd *assume* not, as Phantom Ganon also appeared to take no damage when simply throwing any of those elemental items at him, but that may be something that can be validated on another question!